# Auto-Rig Pro Hand Rigging Issue

Tags: rigging, armature, add-on, bones

I'm trying to use an add-on in Blender named Auto-Rig Pro, which, as the name suggests, automatically rigs your mesh. Everywhere on the model it does a pretty good job. You pinpoint the shoulder, neck, chin, spine root, ankles, and wrists, and it rigs it pretty darn well.

The only problem is the hands look a little bit wonky, and since I'm pretty new to rigging, I'm not sure if I am on the right track or completing something wrong,.

[image]

Comment: so I guess you need to go in Edit mode and extend the bones a bit so that they match the fingers, then parent again?

Comment: Oh so the bones going into each other isn't a problem? That's the only concerning thing for me, it looks like it wouldn't work out once I've generated a rig. I'll try that though thanks!

Comment: there are bones that are made to control the mesh (their Deform option is enabled) and bones that are made to control these deform bones, you must make sure that you move all of them in Edit mode so that they match the mesh

Answer (score 1):

If you study the bones of a hand, you'll see that what we think of as the palm is really just the base of all the fingers connecting almost directly to the wrist. These bones should follow a similar structure.

I have literally just finished sorting out the hands in an auto-rig and this is what I had to do. This is in the step before you bind the rig.

In *Edit Mode* move each bone end to a knuckle or joint, near the top (the muscles are mostly underneath the fingers rather than uniformly surrounding the bone, and on top the bones are closer to the surface). Also it's a good idea to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>R</kbd> rotate each bone so that the Z axis goes through each joint, that way you won't get wonky gimbals after it's finished rigging.

Also check the rest of the rig this way to make sure everything is going to move as you want it to. Then hit Bind and it should be fine.